# sql join with condition on key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I want to join table A and table B in such a way that if you find a match in table B, the match has to meet a condition. If you do not find the match in table B that meets condition, then join the table A with a NULL value. So in the results I should have all the records of table A with some records Joined from B and with some NULLes. **I am surprised the following code does not work.** It returns more records than it should - unfortunately I cannot afford to run it to the end because the tables are too big. Either the condition on date does not work or the condition on key is not well defined or it makes some other JOIN type.

**Example**:

```
A.Key | B.Key | B.Category
.....   .....   ..........
Johny | Johny | Pretty
Katte | Katte | Ugly 
Anne  | no match in Table B
```

**Expected results**:

```
A.Key | B.Category
.....   ..........
Johny | Pretty
Katte | NULL
Anne  | NULL
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @date1 datetime
DECLARE @date2 datetime
SET @date1 = '2014-01-01T00:00:00.000'
SET @date2 = '2014-12-31T23:59:59.997'<br>
SELECT Key.A, B.[Category] 
FROM TableA as A
LEFT JOIN TableB as B
on A.[Key]=B.[Key] AND B.[Category]='Pretty' 
WHERE A.[Date] between @date1 and @date2
```

Comment: More rows? Are there duplicate key values in one of the tables (or both)?

Comment: can u add some sample data and what will be the result on that sample data?

Comment: Yes.. 'More records than it should' is a bit vague but it implies that it isn't a 1-1 join. If both tables have 1000 rows and it's a propr 1-1 join you can expect 1000 rows to be returned. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(name NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(name NVARCHAR(MAX), cat NVARCHAR(MAX))


INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Johny')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Johny')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Katte')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Anne')


INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('Johny', 'Ugly')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('Johny', 'Pretty')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('Katte', 'Ugly')
```

--Select N1

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name, t2.cat FROM @t1 as t1
LEFT JOIN @t2 as t2 on t1.name = t2.name AND t2.cat='Pretty'
```

--Select N2

```
    ;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   t1.name ,
                        t2.cat ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.name ORDER BY t1.name ) AS rownum
               FROM     @t1 AS t1
                        LEFT JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
                                               AND t2.cat = 'Pretty'
             )
    SELECT  name, cat
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   rownum = 1
```

Results:

```
Anne    NULL
Johny   Pretty
Katte   NULL
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I am surprised that I have to use DISTINCT A.Key (or 't1.name' as you wrote) because in table A I have all values distinct in column A.Key. Without that DISTINCT I got more records after LEFT JOIN than was originally in table A. Why?

Comment: because join will multiply result on same keys. if you have 2 johny in one table and 3 johny in another u will get 6 rows.

Also if you don't like distinct you can also group results to exclude duplicates.

Comment: I have a suspicion that DISTINCT works slow. Is there no way to form proper conditions in ON and WHERE clause?

Comment: It should not, unless you have millions of rows in result. Of course there should be many ways of doing this select. I have just given you 1 example.

Comment: Yes DISTINCT works slow and this is a prime example of just using distinct instead of solving the real problem, which is that you have a one to many join.